# Python formatted string literals for objects

Tags: python, python-3.6

one of a very cool new feature of Python3.6 is the implementation of Formatted string literals (https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498).

Unfortunately, it does not behave like the well known format() function:

```
>> a="abcd"
>> print(f"{a[:2]}")
>> 'ab'
```

As you see, slicing is possible (actually all python functions on string).
But `format()` will not work with slicing:

```
>> print("{a[:2]}".format(a="abcd")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Is there a way to get the functionality of the new formatted string literals on string objects??

```
>> string_object = "{a[:2]}"   # may also be comming from a file
>> # some way to get the result 'ab' with 'string_object'
```

Comment: No. According to the Docs, it wouldn't make sense: https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings As far as I can see, it is syntactic sugar for .format() anyways.

Comment: You can technically do it with `eval()`. This is a bad idea in general, but in this case it's doubly difficult to assure safety because the format string itself can contain arbitrary Python code. So even if you parse the string first (`ast.parse()`) and make sure it only contains a single format string, that single format string is just as dangerous as `eval()` itself.

Answer (score 1):

The `str.format` syntax does not and will not support the full range of expressions that the newer f-strings will. You'll have to manually evaluate the slice expression outside of the string and supply it to the format function instead:

```
a = "abcd"
string_object = "{a}".format(a = a[:2])
```

It should also be noted there are [subtle differences](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#differences-between-f-string-and-str-format-expressions) between the syntax allowed by f-strings and `str.format`, so that the former is not strictly a superset of the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, `str.format` tries to cast the indexes to a `str` first before applying them, that's why you get that error; it tries to index the string with `str` indices:

```
a = "abcd" 
>>> a[:'2']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

It really isn't meant for cases like that; `"{a[::]}".format(a=a)` would probably be evaluated as `a[:':']` too I'd guess.

This is one of the reasons `f-strings` came about, in order to support any Python expressions' desire to be formatted.